# How to add an OpenID connect authentication to my web server?

Tags: apache, webserver, openid-connect, openid

Our product is going to be installed on premise and we're going to use node.js server or Apache or something else.
I'd like the authentication to be OpenID connect compatible and would like to use a ready and Openid connect certified solution. What is the best way and which open source package can I use?